# BigO Calculation of Loops

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics, computer-science, computational-complexity

I'm reading the BigO calculation. For the following snippet, for the worst-case scenario of the inner loop, `n*(n*8)` is given, but for the outer loop, `4n` is given. If `4` is the operation count of the outer for loop (1 for assignment, 1 for comparison, and 2 for incremental, respectively), why don't we apply the same logic to the inner one? That is, `8*n` for the inner loop and `4*n` for the outer loop. Shouldn't the outcome be `32n^2`? However, the book says (albeit seeming wrong to me)

The worst case is when the array doesn't contain duplicates and is of size `n` (= `numbers.length`):

- For the outer loop, we have `4*n` operations
- For the inner loop, we have `n*(n*8)` operations
- In total, we have `4n + 8n^2` operations

```
public boolean containsDuplicates(int[] numbers) {
     for (int i=0; i<numbers.length; i++) { // 4 operations
       for (int j=0; j<numbers.length; j++) { // 4 operations
         if (i != j && numbers[i] == numbers[j]) return true; // 4 operations
} }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: The initialization of $i$ only happens once and for $j$ only $n$ times. Does the author define what he means by operations? Is $i\lt\text{ numbers.length}$ two operations or one?